# How to plot a non-commuting graph?

Tags: graph-theory

---

I'm studying non-commuting graphs in the Erdos problem. Although I'll also study infinity groups, I'd like to add some examples of non-commuting graphs of finite groups, to become more visual . Does someone know a good way to plot a non-commuting graph (the vertex are the elements of the group and they are joined iff $[x,y]$ is not trivial) in programs like GeoGebra? I can do it to groups with small order, but when it comes to greater order, like $D_{12}$, it's difficult to make the graph symmetric, for example. I'll be glad if someone could help me.

=======

**I figured out!**

The answer is, create a (simple) function on GAP that, given $G$ a finite group, it will calculate the edges of the non commutative graph, in terms of some generators (normally inside of $S_n$).

Then, you just take this list and change each generator to something more simple in terms of writing (I used the "find and replace" and it was fast). Than, you put this list in the software **Mathematica** and it plots the graph. You can also change the vertices and edges color, change the style of the graph, etc.

I found pretty useful. My first attempt was through **Geogebra** and I DON'T recommend whatsoever for this kind of work.

That's that the function that my advisor Cristina Acciarri and I constructed for GAP:

```
NC2:= function (G)
local V, lati, y, v, temp, r;
V:= Difference( G, Centre(G));
lati:=[];

for v in V do
temp:=Difference(V,[v]);
r:=Filtered(temp, y-> v*y<>y*v);
for y in r do
if not([v,y] in lati) and not([y,v] in lati) then
Add(lati,[v,y]);
fi;
od;
od;

return(lati); 

end;
```

To exemplify, let $D_8$ the dihedral group of order $8$. To obtain the non commutative graph of $D_8$ we proceed the following way on GAP:

```
gap> Read("C:/Users/vinicius/Desktop/NC2.txt");
gap> G:=DihedralGroup(IsPermGroup,8);
Group([ (1,2,3,4), (2,4) ])

gap> NC2(G);
[ [ (2,4), (1,2)(3,4) ], [ (2,4), (1,2,3,4) ], [ (2,4), (1,4,3,2) ], 
[ (2,4), (1,4)(2,3) ], [ (1,2)(3,4), (1,2,3,4) ], [ (1,2)(3,4), (1,3) ], 
[ (1,2)(3,4), (1,4,3,2) ], [ (1,2,3,4), (1,3) ], [ (1,2,3,4), (1,4)(2,3) ],
[ (1,2)(3,4), (1,3) ], [ (1,2)(3,4), (1,4,3,2) ], [ (1,2,3,4), (1,3) ],
[ (1,2,3,4), (1,4)(2,3) ],  [ (1,3), (1,4,3,2) ], [ (1,3), (1,4)(2,3) ], 
[ (1,4,3,2), (1,4)(2,3) ] ]
gap>
```

Then you just need to substitute (2,4) for 1, (1,2) for 2, for instance, and then put this list at **Mathematica** with the right command for graphs.

The result is:

[image]

---

PS: I converted this image ps to jpeg online to post here, so I might not be in its best quality.

Comment: Can you recommend some text for non-commuting graphs?

Comment: "Non-commuting graph of a group" - A.Abdollahi, S. Akbari, H.R. Maimani. (2006). This article explores how properties of non-commuting graph of a group effect on his own properties. They also prove result to well-know groups. There's another article that is not exactly about non-commuting graphs, but a problem that involves them: " A problem of Paul Erdos on groups" , B.H.Neuman (1975). (: .

Comment: @Rebeca_c_s: glad that you've found a way to do this. Perhaps you can post this as an answer to your question then.